# Looking for Ubuntu minimal VM

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm searching for an Ubuntu virtual image based off 14.04/14.10 Server edition minmal install which can work on Virtualbox.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/trusty/current/

Vagrant pulls some of its images from that site and runs them with VirtualBox by default. 
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/

Answer (score 1):

You can also spin your own minimal/customized image using [vmbuilder](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html). While there are claims that it is going to be deprecated, as of 14.04 it works perfectly fine to produce images for kvm and vmware hypervisors, the vmdk disks for the vmware images can be used to create a virtualbox VM.